# Windows only boots from GRUB2 if disk is selected to boot from in BIOS first

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub

I'm trying to figure out how come the only way I'm able to boot into Windows is this way on my HP laptop:

1. Open up boot menu
2. Select disk containing Windows as the option to boot into
3. This doesn't boot into Windows, I just get boot menu again
4. Boot into GRUB on other drive
5. Select windows to boot into

Normally I wouldn't care, but the issue is that it beeps at me like three times during this entire process, and annoys my roommates. My partitioning scheme is somewhat unorthodox (one drive running Linux/boot/EFI and other drive running Windows/its own efi partition/other linux partition). Do I just figure out how to re-run grub-install or is there something better I could be trying first?

Comment: I already stated it's a laptop

Comment: And I don't really have much interest in any answers that address the beeping over the boot situation for those exact diagnostic reasons you stated

Comment: On some HP's, I find the only way to boot to grub2 is to rename the EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi to "backup.efi", to copy EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi to the Microsoft folder, and to rename it as "bootmgfw.efi".

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you very much, this is a two year later reply because the problem came up again but it was the solution to my answer again